# Can not download file from MongoDB gridFS using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs

I am using nodeJS and expressJS to upload and download file to gridFS following the below tutorial.

https://ciphertrick.com/2017/02/28/file-upload-with-nodejs-and-gridfs-mongodb/

File upload works fine. But when I try to download I can only see the content of the file on browser (e.g image/text). But I am unable to download the physical file. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
    var express = require('express'); 
    var app = express(); 
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/gridfstest');
    var conn = mongoose.connection;
    var multer = require('multer');
    var GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
    var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
    Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    var gfs = Grid(conn.db);

/** Seting up server to accept cross-origin browser requests */
app.use(function(req, res, next) { //allow cross origin requests
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, GET");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

/** Setting up storage using multer-gridfs-storage */
var storage = GridFsStorage({
    gfs : gfs,
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1]);
    },
    /** With gridfs we can store aditional meta-data along with the file */
    metadata: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, { originalname: file.originalname });
    },
    root: 'ctFiles' //root name for collection to store files into
});

var upload = multer({ //multer settings for single upload
    storage: storage
}).single('file');

/** API path that will upload the files */
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err){
             res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
             return;
        }
         res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
    });
});

app.get('/file/:filename', function(req, res){
    gfs.collection('ctFiles'); //set collection name to lookup into

    /** First check if file exists */
    gfs.files.find({filename: req.params.filename}).toArray(function(err, files){
        if(!files || files.length === 0){
            return res.status(404).json({
                responseCode: 1,
                responseMessage: "error"
            });
        }
        /** create read stream */
        var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
            filename: files[0].filename,
            root: "ctFiles"
        });
        /** set the proper content type */
        res.set('Content-Type', files[0].contentType)
        /** return response */
        return readstream.pipe(res);
    });
});

app.listen('3002', function(){
    console.log('running on 3002...');
});
```

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` being returned in the response? And what do you mean by *"see the content of the file on browser "*? How in fact are you trying to "load content to the browser"? As an external link? Or something else? Because if it's "something else" then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: The retrieve application is creating a read stream here. So if I send a get request using "localhost:3002/file/filename" from the browser, the browser returns a response based on mime type of the file stored in gridFS. So if the requested file is image, browser show the image. If it is text file, the browser shows text. But I want to download the file, not load the content in the browser. I need to work with very large file. So my requirement is to download file stored in gridfs. Sorry if I couldn't explain it correctly. I am new to mongoDB and nodeJS.

Comment: But I am asking you is *"What is the Content-Type being returned in the response?"*. Which means that if the `Content-Type` is not something like `image/png` or whatever is appropriate to the actual [MIME Type](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/) then the "browser" does not know what to do with it, and likely just shows garbage. You need to check the header that is actually being returned.

Comment: Should be `res.header("Content-Type", files[0].contentType);` anyway. But check what is being returned in the response and then also check whar was actually stored in the metadata for the "file" in the `files` collection created for the GridFS store.

Comment: I just checked the metadata. Content type is text/plain. If you look into get.app in the code, after creating the read stream content type is set as  res.set('Content-type', files[0].contentType).In response browser is showing actual text inside the file by reading the file. So I am not getting any garbage value. That is not my issue. The issue is I don't want to read the file. I want to download the file from gridFS. And I am not getting any physical file downloaded from this code. The app is just reading the file and dumping it's content in to the browser.

Comment: Dude. "text/plain" will be understood by the browser and it will therefore display it. If you are trying to "force" `text/plain` to "download" then you need to return the content type as something like. `application/octet-stream`. Like I already said "twice" but you still do not seem to be getting it. Browsers will deal with MIME types they recognize. If you want it to do something else then you need to send a type that one will not attempt to display

Comment: Got it. That's the answer I was looking for. As I told you I am new in this so it takes some time for me to understand. Anyway Thanks for your input. I really appreciate it.